# Welcome to Puzzling! Warning: __________

Tags: steganography

> So you're thinking of joining this site.
>   That's fantastic! Amateurs, [experts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all),
>   (yup, puzzling 'experts', who'd've known?)
>   crossword buffs, sequence solvers, lovers
>   of language and enigmatic mathematics, all
>   and sundry are cordially welcome. Don't
>   be afraid, dive in! [Unsolved](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/unanswered) riddles,
>   intriguing [tags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags), and riveting mind-benders await.
>   Network novices, my advice is to check out [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=puzzling.stackexchange.com),
>   take a quick [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), view the latest [activity](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/?tab=active),
>   and visit [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com) if you require assistance.
>   Enough nattering, now. Enjoy your stay –
>   **Qji xvcdgt bn lpgcxcv pi ndjg etgxa!**

Hint:

> The puzzle can be solved without deciphering the last line

Comment: I assume there's more to this than the decoding of the bottom? What exactly are we *looking* for? Even "enigmatic puzzles" have a way to know when you're done.

Comment: @Deusovi removed the enigmatic tag. I guess this is just steganography. My fault for misunderstanding the meaning of the tag.

Comment: 7 words in the warning, 7 links in your riddle, is that a coincidence?

Comment: @Flying_whale yes, the links are just links and unrelated to the puzzle. I originally tagged enigmatic which might have unintentionally sent people on a wild goose chase in the links -_- But it’s just steganography

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the warning must be

> It's addicting

---

Although I made some mistakes when I was originally looking for it, I nevertheless wound up with the correct answer.

However, the correct way to find the warning is simply to

> take the most frequent non-space character for each line.

The clue that led me to the solution was

> alliteration on a few of the lines.

---

Thanks to [Έρικ Κωνσταντόπουλος](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12114/%ce%88%cf%81%ce%b9%ce%ba-%ce%9a%cf%89%ce%bd%cf%83%cf%84%ce%b1%ce%bd%cf%84%cf%8c%cf%80%ce%bf%cf%85%ce%bb%ce%bf%cf%82) for decoding the bold text. I think

> the last letter was helpful in getting the warning.

Comment: @frabjrew Maybe this isn't a surprise, but the reason the message wasn't clear with the program was because I made a mistake when writing it.

Comment: lol. Well there are plenty of letter frequency checker websites out there, for future reference :D

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this is the full answer, but the bold text says:

> But ignore my warning at your peril!

...the question still remains though.

How did I find out?

> I went to http://rot13.com/ and simply checked each possible ROT-N cipher until I got to ROT11, which is the cipher used by the warning.

Comment: Decoded correctly of course, but not the answer.